# Как закрыть форму при закрытии последней вкладки XtraTabControl?

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

Как закрыть форму при закрытии последней вкладки XtraTabControl?

Сейчас есть обработка закрытия вкладки (`XtraTabPage`):

```
private void TabControl_CloseButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (e is ClosePageButtonEventArgs arg) ((XtraTabPage) arg.Page).PageVisible = false;
}
```

Инициализация:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var settings = new CefSettings();
    Cef.Initialize(settings);
    settings.IgnoreCertificateErrors = true;
    txtUrl.Text = @"http://https://ru.stackoverflow.com";
    _chrome = new ChromiumWebBrowser(txtUrl.Text)
    {
        Parent = tabControl.SelectedTabPage,
        Dock = DockStyle.Fill
    };
    _chrome.AddressChanged += Chrome_AddressChanged;
    _chrome.TitleChanged += Chrome_TitleChanged;
}

//Add Page
private void TabControl_CustomHeaderButtonClick(object sender, CustomHeaderButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var ctrl=new ChromiumWebBrowser(@"http://https://ru.stackoverflow.com");
    var page = new XtraTabPage(){Text = ctrl.Address};
    page.Controls.Add(ctrl);
    tabControl.TabPages.Add(page);
    ctrl.AddressChanged += Chrome_AddressChanged;
    ctrl.TitleChanged += Chrome_TitleChanged;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Вариант № 1**: сразу после закрытия вкладки проверять, остались ли еще видимые:

```
using System.Linq;
...
private void TabControl_CloseButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    if (e is ClosePageButtonEventArgs arg) ((XtraTabPage) arg.Page).PageVisible = false;
    //если не осталось видимых
    var hasVisiblePages = tabControl.TabPages.Any(p => p.PageVisible);
    //Закрываем форму
    if (!hasVisiblePages) Close();
```

`tabControl` можно получить из `sender` если обработчик события используется для нескольких разных элементов.

```
var tabControl = (XtraTabControl) sender;
```

**Вариант № 2:** Удалять вкладки, а не скрывать их, тогда можно воспользоваться `TabPages.Count`:

```
private void xtraTabControl1_CloseButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var arg = (ClosePageButtonEventArgs) e;
    tabControl.TabPages.Remove((XtraTabPage) arg.Page);
    if (tabControl.TabPages.Count==0) Close();
```

Вариант может не подойти если эти вкладки планируется отображать снова.

**Вариант № 3:** Как советует поддержка ([Visible count on tab page](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q232776/visible-count-on-tab-page)) создать наследника `XtraTabControl` из которого будет доступно свойство `ViewInfo` затем воспользоваться свойством `BaseTabControlViewInfo.VisiblePagesCount` и открыть к нему доступ извне:

```
class TabControlWithVisibleCount : XtraTabControl
{
    public int VisiblePagesCount 
    {
        get { return ViewInfo.VisiblePagesCount; }
    }
}
```

, после этого использовать свой класс и его свойство:

```
private void TabControl_CloseButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    if (e is ClosePageButtonEventArgs arg) ((XtraTabPage) arg.Page).PageVisible = false;
    if (tabControl.VisiblePagesCount == 0) Close();
```

P.S. Поддержка DevExpress отвечает достаточно оперативно и предоставляет примеры.

Comment: первый вариант сработал, спасибо!